# How to pimp boost-python wrapped library without recompiling it?

Tags: boost-python

There is a boost-python wrapped library (written in C++). For performance reasons I would like to write some C++ code to invoke some functions from the C++ library directly.

One way to go would be to create a fork of this library and add the functions I have in mind directly to the C++ code.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without recompiling this library?

Comment: Why can't use use existing C++ library as a shared library when implementing new functionality?

Comment: Hm... That seems like a reasonable option. I'll definitely consider this.